# c++ accumulate with both aggregated value and original value

Tags: c++, reduce, higher-order-functions, accumulate

I had a usecase where I want to accumulate a `sum` variable while iterating over the array and do binary operation on every two neighbors. `accumulate` aka `reduce` comes to mind. But I find myself writing this

```
  int sum = 0;
  auto result = // this result is discarded. its always the last element value
      accumulate(v.begin() + 1, v.end(), *v.begin(),
                 [&sum, &duration](int left, int right) {
                   sum += min(right - left, duration);
                   return right; // only care about the side effect in the lambda
                 });
```

I think this is ugly but I couldn't find a way to eliminate the extra variable sum used to keep track of the aggregated value. What I was doing is equal to this traditional loop.

```
  for (vector<int>::size_type i = 1; i < v.size(); i++) {
    sum += min(v[i] - v[i - 1], duration);
  }
```

Is there a way I can not use a int sum and just return the desired sum from the reduce function?

some expected result

```
// second param is the "duration" but its not important. 
vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
REQUIRE(foo(v, 3) == 5);
vector<int> v1{1, 2, 3};
REQUIRE(foo(v1, 1) == 3);
vector<int> v2{1, 5, 7};
REQUIRE(foo(v2, 2) == 6);
```

Comment: What is this "findPoisonedDuration"?

Comment: @Justin my bad. Ill rename some of the stuff